# Is it possible that string's one part has tension and other part does not has any tension?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

you have a massless and inextensible string connected to a pulley with some moment of inertia , and if pulley does not slip over string in some setup, IS THAT POSSIBLE TO HAVE TENSION IN ONE SIDE OF STRING WHILE NO TENSION ON OTHER SIDE

Comment: I think you're having some misconception regarding the force of tension. Tension is a kind of restoring force, if you pull the rubber band from one side the tension acts in the opposite direction of your pull.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  If in a gravitational field, put a mass on one end of the string and nothing on the other end.  With a massless string and no slipping, there will be tension on the side of the string with the mass due to the moment of inertia of the pulley, but the tension with no mass attached to it will be zero.

Obviously, if the pulley were massless, there would be no tension anywhere, and the acceleration of the system would be $g$, the acceleration due to gravity.